# Open a file using Java application

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to open the file using Runtime. This is similar to opening windows command prompt, and then executing the command.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class OpenFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "E:\\Myfile.txt";
        try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            rt.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "start"});
            rt.exec(new String[]{fileName});
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The command prompt is opening successfully. But the file Myfile.txt is not opening. I'm getting the below error in console:

```
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess: E:\Myfile.txt error=193
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:451)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:591)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:464)
    at OpenFile.main(OpenFile.java:10)
```

How to open the file successfully?

Comment: I can't put my finger on it (never actually used something like this myself) but if I'm not mistaken there is a way you can use on both Windows based and other platform-based computers.
I recommend looking for that, instead of limiting your application to just .exe files

anyway, this might be of some help:


http://about-java-programming.blogspot.be/2007/02/javaioioexception-createprocess.html

Comment: @Stultuske you are thinking about [java.awt.Desktop#open()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to execute `fileName` in `Runtime` object, which is wrong! Try like below:

```
rt.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "start", fileName});
```

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer, but I think it's important to describe what exactly is happening in the current version of the application.

In this part of your code;

```
        rt.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "start"});
        rt.exec(new String[]{fileName});
```

You are executing an external command. To quote the question,

> similar to opening windows command prompt, and then executing the
>   command

What you need to realize is that whatever you've given as the string gets executed. It isn't queued or anything. Thus, re-reading your code, you are asking your program to execute 2 different commands. The first would look like;

```
cmd.exe /c start
```

Which if run on the windows command prompt executes without issues. The second "command" your program attempts to execute looks like this;

```
E:\Myfile.txt
```

Try typing that into the command prompt - it will produce an error. Probably something like "command not found". This is what the exception `java.io.IOException: CreateProcess` is telling you. That Java was not able to create the new process you asked it to.

Now, as for actually answering the OP, I suggest this;

```
        rt.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "start", fileName});
```

Which, unfortunately looks exactly like an earlier answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unable to upvote. Not enough reputation.